# XPath predicate absolute vs relative descendant test?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'd like to query XML to retrieve each `ElementICareAbout` when it has two `ElementICareAbout2` children that themselves have `AttributeICareAbout`; the value of `AttributeICareAbout` is not relevant.

The XPath query I have below seems correct to me, but it returns every `ElementICareAbout` that contains a single `ElementICareAbout2` with `AttributeICareAbout`.

**XPath:**

```
//ElementICareAbout[@AttributeICareAbout='ValueICareAbout']
                   [count(//ElementICareAbout2[@AttributeICareAbout2]) > 1]
```

**XML:**

```
<RootElement>
    <ArbitraryElement>
        <ArbitraryElement2>
            <!-- DO WANT THE BELOW ELEMENT, CONTAINS TWO ElementICareAbout2 
                 CHILDREN WITH ArbitraryAttribute -->
            <ElementICareAbout AttributeICareAbout="ValueICareAbout">
                <ArbitraryElement4>
                    <ElementICareAbout2 AttributeICareAbout2="ArbitraryValue"/>
                </ArbitraryElement4>                
                <ArbitraryElement5>
                    <ArbitraryElement6>
                        <ElementICareAbout2 AttributeICareAbout2="ArbitraryValue"/>
                    </ArbitraryElement6>
                </ArbitraryElement5>
            </ElementICareAbout>
            <!-- DON'T WANT THE BELOW ELEMENT, LACKING TWO ElementICareAbout2
                 CHILDREN WITH ArbitraryAttribute -->
            <ElementICareAbout AttributeICareAbout="ValueICareAbout">
                <ArbitraryElement4>
                    <ElementICareAbout2 AttributeICareAbout2="ArbitraryValue"/>
                </ArbitraryElement4>                
                <ArbitraryElement5>
                    <ArbitraryElement6>
                        <ElementICareAbout2 ArbitraryAttribute="ArbitraryValue"/>
                    </ArbitraryElement6>
                </ArbitraryElement5>
            </ElementICareAbout>
        </ArbitraryElement2>
        <ArbitraryElement3>
        </ArbitraryElement3>
    </ArbitraryElement>
</RootElement>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the predicate involving `ElementICareAbout2` relative (`.//`) rather than absolute (`//`):

```
//ElementICareAbout[@AttributeICareAbout='ValueICareAbout']
                   [count(.//ElementICareAbout2[@AttributeICareAbout2]) > 1]
```